# deploying localDB files for outlook addin with windows installer install shield (ISLE)

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installshield, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm trying for some time now to create an installer for my outlook addin using windows installer install shield (ISLE)

I'm using visual 2013, with this guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx

the installation passes, but my addin doesn't work properly becuase of my localDB.

I've been trying unseccesfully to find info about how to add sqlLocalDB to the deployed machine, and what is the right way to do so.

what I did is:

1. i'm adding the database.mdf and database_log.lfg files to the installer project ('project assistant' -> add files), is that the right way of doing so?
2. on 'redistributable' I clicked on both 'Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express SP1 localDB (X64) & (X86)

but after my installation, I keep getting errors because is seems the my deployed machine can't write to the localDB.

I found this: http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield20helplib/Content/helplibrary/SQL-LocalDBConx.htm
but it doesn't seem to help, because I can't find the second part in my install shield (using Native Client 11 ODBC driver)

this is my connection string in App.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="OutlookAddIn.Properties.Settings.DatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Is there any information on how to add and use localDB with this install tool?

Update:
It seems like the major problem is that partial classes don't work for me. I don't know why are they working on my PC but not on the deployed machine (I put there .NET 3.5 ,4 , 4.5 and still don't work)

Comment: Does this have to be done with InstallShield? If not, it might be an idea to try switching to the WiX installer. I know nothing about your specific problem, but my understanding is that WiX is better than InstallShield, and there is probably more help to be found on the Internet. For example, a Google search for "sqlLocalDB wix installer" produces lots of links that might be helpful.

Comment: PS. If you're not familiar with the WiX installer, note that there is another program called Wix for building websites - the two programs have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Thank you @RenniePet , I'm not familiar with Wix, If I won't get an answer soon, I will try to work it.